# TFS - Link a commit to a working item

Tags: git, team-foundation-server

I want to link a commit to a working item (User story or Task).

I thought it is enough to add the item id with an hashtag to the commit message (e.g. "Implemented user story #124") but it seems this only works if the commit is a part of a pull request. How is this possible without pull requests?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of tfs do you use? I`ve checked that on my two tfs (2015 and 2018). tfs 2015 does not support # for work items in commits. tfs 2018 supports that. So maybe you need to update your tfs?

Additionally you can find the workaround for commits here: [Cannot use #ID in commit message to link to a user story](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/280103/cannot-use-id-in-message-of-commit-to-link-a-user.html)

Comment: We use TFS 2018 and I don't want to use the Team Explorer to commit my stuff, I'm using SourceTree.

Comment: Ok, I`ll also try it soon...